# Determine the delay in mirroring ( mirroring is done by using rsync and rsh )

Tags: algorithm, bash, rsync, mirroring, rsh

I have a master server, that crawls data on web, and do indexing. And after that it starts mirroring to all the mirror server.

For that I use **rsync and rsh**.

But before start updating in mirror server, it takes time. I want to find where that delay occurs.

**My understanding**

It might be takes time in reverse DNS Lookup.

**My questions**

**EDITED**

1. Is it right to add some log in **rsh.c** code  **or in rsync code**
2. If first question's answer is yes, then I want to make a list of time consumed when Reverse DNS Lookup is **enabled** and when Reverse DNS Lookup is **disabled**, so tell me what can do for that?

Tell me where can I add log to note the time consumed?

If my understanding and questions are not upto mark or relevant according to the task that I want, then please correct me, and give me better path, so that I can achieve my goal.

Thanks in advance. Looking for your kind response.

**Edit No. 2**

Basically I am analyzing the time consumed to determine the delay reason. Nothing to modufy the existing code.

My task is to analyze the code , and find the reason of delay. Thats it.

I think now all the things of my task is clear to you.

Answer (score 1):

Before changing rsh, you may try using strace to see which system calls take longer.

strace -c will produce a list of system calls and % of time used by those calls.
(should help with the second question also)

For the DNS look-up to be evident you can use ltrace:

example:

```
ltrace -c -o log.txt wget http://dkjflsdfjka/
```

Then log.txt will have something like:

```
root@host:~# head log.txt 
% time seconds usecs/call calls function 
------ ----------- ----------- --------- -------------------- 
74.27 0.130779 130779 1 getaddrinfo 
6.63 0.011680 33 344 strlen 
3.05 0.005371 35 152 free 
2.98 0.005255 35 147 malloc 
2.74 0.004830 38 127 fgets
```

then you can see ... the getaddrinfo call is taking most of the time

Comment: First thing, change is not required in rsh in my task. I just have to find where the delay occurs by logging at some point.

Comment: strace -T -o logfile.txt ?

Comment: I run this command to see the outputs. Yes, it is helpful for me. But, when I read `rsh.c` , it seems very complex. Can you help me to detect where can I put log , to check reverse DNS lookup.

Comment: Modifying rsh.c is not necessary from my point of view, strace should give you all the information you need. Anyway, I can't help you with the code.

Comment: According to you, just put this command when there is a copying of data from master to mirror starts. Am I right ?

Comment: `strace -c ls | awk '{print $2}' | tail -1` not giving the desired output , i.e., total time consumed.

Comment: Without a sample of what are you trying to do, I can not advise you further. `strace -c ls | awk '{print $2}' | tail -1` doesn't "work" because strace uses STDERR ... if you want it to work you should redirect STDERR to STDOUT: `strace -c ls 2>&1 | awk '{print $2}' | tail -1`

Comment: I explained all the things that I am trying to do in my question.
See my Edit no. 2 portion.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25283/discussion-between-sorin-and-jhamb)

Comment: Please join the conversation in chat room

Comment: When I run a command a command 
`ltrace -c -o log.txt rsync -avzr ~/data/accounts xyz@10.40.55.76:`
. Then it shows 87% time consumed in `select function`, it didn't show `getaddrinfo function`, that is the issue for me. There might be a possibility that I am working in my college LAN, thats why it didn't show `getaddrinfo function` while runing above command.
Am I right ?

Comment: You didn't get the getaddrinfo because it's not the one consuming most of the time. `select` sounds about right for rsync.

Comment: Please start the chat, if you have time , please. Otherwise help me solve my problem through comments. I have a lots of questions yet to ask from you. If possible please take some time for me.

Comment: Tell me one thing, how much time this ltrace logging takes. Everytime logging may creates extra overhead. Isn't it ? Is this possible to make a condition, just like, if reverse DNS lookup takes time more than any limit, then makes a log.

Comment: and,  `getaddrinfo` system call is used for forward DNS lookup. But in my case I have to check reverse DNS lookup.